# Probability of even number of successes in a series of independent trials

Tags: probability, generating-functions

Consider a series of independent trials at each of which there is a success of a failure with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$ respectively. I am finding it difficult to derive the probability of even number of successes occurring at the nth trial. Any assistance will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use induction.  If $P_n$ is the probability of even number of successes in n trials, then

$$ P_n = p(1-P_{n-1}) + (1-p)P_{n-1}$$

This results in

$$ P_n = \frac{1+(1-2p)^n}{2}$$

Comment: Nice answer ...

Comment: @Heisenberg: Thanks

Comment: Can you please show how you got the final result , I tried using probability generating function but got stuck

Comment: @simran: Rearrange the recurrence relation as $P_n = p +(1-2p)P_{n-1}$. This is a linear difference equation which has a general solution of the form $P_n = \alpha + \beta (1-2p)^n$.  Since the equation is of first order, one initial condition is needed.  That is $P_1 = 1-p$ because in one trial the only way to get an even number of successes is 0 successes with probability $q = 1-p$.  Substituting the general solution in the difference equation and applying the initial condition yields $\alpha = \beta = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: There is a general theory of linear difference equations which resembles that of linear differential equations.  In this case, we have a first order non-homogeneous equation and the general solution is the sum of the general solution to the homogeneous equation $P_n = (1-2p)P_{n-1}$  and a constant particular solution.

Comment: @rrl : Thank you , although I wasn't expecting a reply on such a old answer ..

Answer (score 4):

The generating function for the probability of success in $n$ trials is
$$f(x) = (1-p+px)^n$$
The generating function for the cases where the number of successes is even is
$$\frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2}$$
To find the total probability of success in an even number of trials, just set $x=1$ in the generating function:
$$\frac{f(1) + f(-1)}{2} = \frac{1 + (1-2p)^n}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since this follows a binomial distribution, your chance of a particular number of successes $s$ is
$$\binom{n}{s}p^s(1-p)^{n-s}$$

So you could take
$$\sum_{s=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n}{2s}p^{2s}(1-p)^{n-2s}$$