# If m things are distributed among a men and b women, find the probability that the number of things received by men is odd ?( given, $a$ $\leq$ $b$)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If m things are distributed among '$a$' men and '$b$' women, find the probability that the number of things received by men is odd ? ( given, $a$ $\leq$ $b$)

> If the expression is known, then it can be shown easily by induction. But for this question how can I derive the expression.

Comment: Note that this is exactly the same question as if there were two people, named AllTheMen and AllTheWomen, and the $m$ things are distributed between the two.

Comment: Something is not quite clear; are the things distributed so each person receives at most one thing? Or are they handed out independently?

Comment: I advise using a combinatorics approach, expressing the answer as $$p = \frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$$ where $D$ is the total number of different possible distributions, and $N$ is the total number of distributions where the men receive an odd number of items.

Comment: @GregMartin: If the things are distinguishable, it is not the same question: for $m=a=2,b=1$, for instance, the probability is $\frac49$, but if you change $a$ to $1$, the probability rises to $\frac12$.

Comment: I was thinking about something. Although not sure I decided to post it in the comments.Let $A_i$ be the event that the $i-th$ object goes to the men. Then we can consider the case where $m$ is odd and find $P(m)$[The probability that exactly $m$ no of events will occur  ]by Jordan's first theorem and then we go on to $m-1$ and in this way it can go onto $(m+1)/2$ steps

Comment: Since it's a discussion if anyone could point out my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is here:

https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/probability-even-number-successes-n-independent-bernoulli-tr-chapter-5.1-problem-32e-solution-9780131453401-exc

[Probability of even number of successes in a series of independent trials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794911/probability-of-even-number-of-successes-in-a-series-of-independent-trials)

In your notation, it's shown that the formula is:

$$\frac{1}{2}\Big[1+(1-\frac{2a}{a+b})^m\Big]$$

In their notation, your $m$ is their $n$.  To convert your problem to a Bernoulli Experiment, let $a+b = c$ and let $P= \frac{a}{c}$.  Then assuming that the things are distributed randomly with uniform probability across your $c$ people, that's the probability of a 'success,' i.e. the probability of distributing an item to one of the men.